# Android custom keyboard - Class not found (XML)

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

What i want to do:

Create a custom keyboard, since default keyboards are not sufficient.

Keys needed: `0-9, '-', ',', 'e', 'del'` and one empty one where i can put the logo.

I already achieved this in iOS with inputAccessoryView, but after some research i believe there is  nothing similar in android. So i decided to go the way of creating my own Keyboard in xml.

Tested Source is from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/qwerty.xml).

But the XML Designer in Android Studio tells me: The following classes could not be found:

- Keyboard (Fix Build Path)
- Row (Fix Build Path)

Tip: Try to build the project.

I have no clue what this error is about, and stated tips by android studio aren't doing anything.
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Ok, to make it clear: Android Studio doesn't know the xml tag "< Keyboard >". Why? Do i need some sort of special import in the manifest file? or sth in the gradle files?

EDIT 2: To make it really clear what happens to be my problem here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you created your xml keyboard in `res/xml/qwerty.xml` or where have you created it?

Comment: i created it in res/layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do a custom keyboard!

The Keyboard design must be in `res/xml/qwerty.xml`.

I would recommend you to follow [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial, where it is explained how to do it from scratch.

Good luck and hope it helps! :)

Comment: This way is nice and everything, but i don't want to give  the user a chance on choosing what keyboard he wants to use. i just want a keyboard, with the keys specified in the question, exclusively for my app. and i think that should work without IME's... Look for edit in question

Comment: Ok, now that keyboard.xml is in XML folder, it works. But the new question is, there is obviously no possibility to show this xml file in the designer, right? Does that mean i have to create this xml and try it to see if it looks like how i want it to?

Comment: From what I know, it is not possible to show it in the designer, you just can specify the rows but not much more... If it works, you could upvote and accept the answer :)